# Appium 1.5.0 Desktop error: could not connect to server are you sure its running

Tags: uiview, android-emulator, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Background info:

- Mac book air : version 10.13.4
- Appium desktop: 1.5
- Android studio:  3.1.2
- Emulator:  Nexus 5
- Operating system:  Oreo or 8.0

I was able to successfully create my desired capabilities on the appium desktop. 1.5.0. These are the desired capabilities:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8.0",
  "deviceName": "jacquelineNexus5",
  "automationName": "Appium",
  "app": "/Users/jacquelinegeorge/Documents/Appium/Apps/ApiDemos-debug.apk"
}
```

I just ran it again and and I got the the following error message:

> 'could not connect to server are you sure its running'.

I don't have any internet issues what exactly does this mean?

More importantly how do I fix it?

I want to also had the emulator was running at the time as well and the server was running was fine  far as I am aware. I am very confused.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has this issue please make sure you have 'automatic server' tab clicked.

Mods if you wish to delete this please feel free to do so